# How to get the field values as a dictionary

Tags: django

I have create a model `Role` as shown below.

```
class Role(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
```

I am trying to get the `role_name` of the record which has `primary_key=2`. So, far I have tried to do it like this -

```
Role.objects.get(pk=2)
```

But the problem with this is it returns the `id` of the instance i.e `2` which doesn't make sense as I already have it.

So, I tried again using `values` and `filter` like this -

```
Role.objects.values('role_name').filter(pk=2)
```

Now, in this case it does return me the `role_name` but as an array of objects.

As, the database table `Role` will always have one record I am expecting it to return a dictionary or just the value of it.

Comment: Try: `Role.objects.get(pk=2).role_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to do this -

```
Role.objects.value('id', 'role_name').get(pk=2)
```

`get()` will always return one object and if in case the query has more than one object than it will raise and exception.

Comment: If a `get()` call with `primary key` lookup returns more than 1 result, it seems that something is wrong with your structure. I recommend you to seek the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem with this is it returns the `id` of the instance

No. It will either return a `Role` object or throw `Role.DoesNotExist` exception.

```
role = Role.objects.get(pk=2)
role_name = role.role_name
```

Comment: Put a `assertIsInstance(role, Role)` after `role = Role.objects.get(pk=2)` to validate return type. Try it once. Or read the documentation maybe.